# react-jsonp giving a CORB error in a React App

Tags: reactjs, cors, fetch

**Edit**
based on suggestions tried doing it with fetch, now I am getting this

[image]

[image]

I am trying to get data from gnews.io/api in a simple react app.I am learning React and the solution might have been to easy but I am stuck here and cant figure out what is wrong and I keep getting this error

```
fetch-jsonp.js:88 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://gnews.io/api/v4/top-headlines?country=us&token=myapi with MIME type application/json.
```

funny thing is that if I copy this url `https://gnews.io/api/v4/top-headlines?country=us&token=MYAPI&callback=jsonp_1642257010280_37644`
and paste it in the browser I am getting the desired response.

Would really appreciate any sort of help

this is the useEffect function that is making this api call

```
React.useEffect(()=> {
    async function getNewsdata(country){
        try {
            
            let url = `https://www.gnews.io/api/v4/top-headlines?country=pk&token=${API2}`
            let response = await fetchJsonp(url)
            let result = await response.json()
            
            console.log("News Data:", result)
                
                
        } catch (error) {
          console.log("error loading news data: ", error)  
        }
        
    }
    getNewsdata(props.country.trim())
    

},[])
```

Comment: How does `fetchJsonp` look like? Can you show that code?

Comment: its this package https://github.com/camsong/fetch-jsonp

Comment: Are you targeting old browsers? Otherwise why not try simple `fetch`?

Comment: fetch giving a CORS error, even when mode set to "no-cors" its also also not working, I dont want to go to server side and make a call, there surely be a way to do it

Comment: @FurrukhJamal If the response's content type is `application/json`, CORB will kick in (in Chrome) and won't allow you to use JSONP, whether directly or through some third-party tool like `fetch-jsonp`. Plus the `gnews.io`API appears to be configured for CORS (responses contain `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`). If you're having some CORS issue, why not fix that instead of creating more problems for yourself?

Comment: I believe you're using the wrong domain. Try `gnews.io` rather than `www.gnews.io` (which is _not_ configured for CORS).

Comment: @jub0bs is correct. A little bit of debugging in the browser shows the 301 (redirect) response code with the correct URL in the response.

Comment: tried using with gnews.io, with fetch its giving CORS error, with fetch-jsonp its giving me CORB error

Comment: Tell us more about the CORS error, then. Take a screenshot of your browser's Network tab showing the request and response and add it to your question.

Comment: @jub0bs Done attached screenshots

Comment: Why is your request's content type `application/json`? There's something you're not telling us... And why specify a content type if the request has no body? Anyway, if you drop that `Content-Type` header from your request, it won't be preflighted and your problem will be solved.

Comment: yup that fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resorting to [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) is frowned upon nowadays; there are safer alternatives, such as CORS, for cross-origin communication. As the response's content type is `application/json`, using JSONP will not work anyway because it causes [Chrome's CORB feature](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/corb-for-developers) to kick in.

Why not try to solve whatever CORS issue you seem to be having? I'd be very surprised if the API you're using weren't configured for CORS... A casual inspection of [their documentation](https://gnews.io/docs/v4#introduction) reveals that you're using the wrong domain, `www.gnews.io`, instead of `gnews.io`. The former redirects to the latter, but is *not* configured for CORS, which explains your CORS troubles.

Once you use the right domain (`gnews.io`), all your CORS troubles go away. And because there's no longer any need to reach for dirty tricks like JSONP, you can use good old reliable `fetch` rather than some third-party tool.

```js
React.useEffect(()=> {
  async function getNewsdata(country){
    try {        
      let url = `https://gnews.io/api/v4/top-headlines?country=pk&token=${API2}` // gnews.io, not www.gnews.io
      let response = await fetch(url) // fetch, not fetchJsonp
      let result = await response.json()      
      console.log("News Data:", result)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error loading news data: ", error)  
    }     
  }
  getNewsdata(props.country.trim())
},[])
```